# What do you do when you move under a low barrier?

Tags: single-word-requests

Do you duck under it, crouch under it, or is there a better term? This lower position is held only for a very brief moment, so you don't duck under it and remain crouched. The focus is on the quick crossing under the barrier, to move from one side to the other.

Comment: I like to limbo-dance.

Comment: I'm sure 'duck under the barrier' would be the most common way to put it.

Comment: @Erik Kowal The verb 'dance' takes hyponymic objects (danced a jig / tango / waltz). Does 'limbo-dance'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Nope. It's its own 'thing'.

Comment: You'd think it would be more flexible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : for me 'duck under the barrier' seemed to be the best, but I wasn't sure if it doesn't mean to duck under the barrier and stay there, as if you wanted to be hidden under it. If you think it would fit, post it as an answer.

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duck) gives **duck** 2  ...
v.tr.
1. To lower quickly, especially so as to avoid something: ducked his head as the ball came toward him.
...
v.intr.
1. To lower the head or body.
2. To move swiftly, especially so as to escape being seen: ducked behind a bush. // Senses 1 and 1' license the punctive usage, and I'd say 2' licenses the durative sense you mention. // I'd think that 'duck' is too obvious to merit an 'answer', though it's the way I'd say it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To  [stoop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoop)  may describe the action : (from M-W)

> - to bend the body or a part of the body forward and downward sometimes simultaneously bending the knees.

- he stooped under the barrier, striding towards the American checkpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting... *Duck* is very common, but it can mean staying in the position - depending on the context:

"How am I going to get to the door?" "Duck under the barrier" -but, also-
"They're dropping bombs on us!" "Duck under the barrier"

*Limbo* would be understood by most, but it also requires the sarcastic (and very precise) to bend backward, rather than forward.

The most economical way to solve this, I believe, would be to use the term "scooch".  If you say, "Scooch *under*," you are telling someone to stay. If you say "Scooch *by*, you are telling them to pass.

I don't know why, but "Duck by" is not as common. (US)

Comment: Scooch is interesting, but 'scooch by' seems to refer more to a move trough a narrow space: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scooch

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in Oxford (a more common usage), but it's also used the other way... maybe because it sounds like "stoop". I've also heard "scoonch" quite a bit (not in the dictionary - except the Urban Dictionary) which is probably a combination of "scooch" and "crunch"(down).